# Skip footer from csv files in s3 to Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, footer, amazon-athena

I have a problem with create external table in AWS Athena. I have over 1000 csv files, all with header and footer, and i would like to create an Athena table to visualize and analyze all data togheter.

I tried with the following code but it seems that the property to remove the footer does not work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.multi_file_test(
  `value1` string COMMENT '', 
  `value2` string COMMENT '', 
  `value3` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://s3_path'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'areColumnsQuoted'='false',
'skip.header.line.count'='1',
'skip.footer.line.count'='1' <<<--- It doesn't seem to work
```

I get this result

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| from_file1 | A | 1 |
| from_file1 | B | 1 |
| **footer_file1** |  |  |
| from_file2 | A | 2 |
| from_file2 | B | 2 |
| **footer_file2** |  |  |
| from_file3 | A | 3 |
| from_file3 | B | 3 |
| **footer_file3** |  |  |

but I need to get this result:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| from_file1 | A | 1 |
| from_file1 | B | 1 |
| from_file2 | A | 2 |
| from_file2 | B | 2 |
| from_file3 | A | 3 |
| from_file3 | B | 3 |

any suggestion or solution would be great.

I thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Athena engine version 1 then this will not work as it is based on Presto 0.172 where as the property `'skip.footer.line.count'='1'` added in [Presto 0.199](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.199.html?highlight=skip%20footer%20line%20count#hive-changes). You have to switch to Athena engine version 2 which is based on  Presto 0.217 for it to work properly.

I have tested in version 2 and able to see this work. Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-changing.html) for changing versions in Athena.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to do so in amazon athena.

Comment: Refer to @Prabhakar Reddy for a solution to the problem